# d3v3 behavior.zoom restrict mouse drag within the visible viewport

Tags: d3.js

Hello I want to restrict the moving of the map outside of the visible container. 
The issue is visible  [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797) if the user drags the map too much down (images 1 before -2 after)
Any ideas?
[image: Before]
[image: After]